# zimjs library: how to make the zim frame initialization log disappear

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some logs in my chrome console:
[image]

the ZIM FRAME log stems from here, according to the chrome console:

```
this.frame = new zim.Frame({
  scaling: 'fit',
  canvasID: "zimCanvas",
  allowDefault: true,
  ready: () => this.repeatedlyPositionCanvas()
});
```

How do I disable this log from getting printed? It clutters my console

Comment: Note - it is just the green Z that is being logged by ZIM.  The zon=false answer is the right answer by @josh-kelley below.  That will turn off all logs including your own custom zog() logs - zog() being the ZIM wrapper for console.log().  You can also zogg(), zogr(), zogb(), etc. for green, red, blue, and more colors.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at [the source code](https://github.com/danzen/zimjs/blob/master/src/zim.js) (search for `ZIM FRAME` and `zon`), it looks like you can disable all zim.js logging by setting `window.zon = false`. Zim.js appears to evaluate this when its module code first executes. Therefore, depending on your bundler, you may need to do this in a `<script>` tag, before including any of your own scripts, to ensure that it's set in time.

```html
<script>window.zon = false;</script>
```